# Does the alternator have to be a Bosch?

Tags: troubleshooting, oldsmobile

I have a 2003 Oldsmobile Alero 3.4 V6.

I was told that I had to replace my alternator with a Bosch brand because no other brands will work.

Is this true? Do I only have one option and I must get the Bosch because no other brand will work?

Comment: Maybe the parts store "didn't have" another brand, so you had to get Bosch?  Great answer from @Zaid...

Comment: @JPhi1618 : It would seem odd for GM to choose Bosch over Delphi (not that it doesn't happen)

Answer (score 5):

### No, it doesn't have to be a Bosch.

In fact, it looks like the [OEM alternator is made by Delphi](https://alternatorstarterrebuildkits.com/product/130d763/).

The website linked also lists the models that share this alternator (model *130D763*):

```
Make        Model       Engine               Model Years 
CHEVROLET   CAMARO      3.8L V6              1996-1999 
CHEVROLET   CAVALIER    2.2L L4 BI-FUEL      1999 2002 
CHEVROLET   CAVALIER    2.2L L4 CNG          2001 2001 
CHEVROLET   CAVALIER    2.2L L4 OHV          1999 2002 
CHEVROLET   CAVALIER    2.4L L4              1996 2002 
CHEVROLET   MALIBU      2.4L L4              1997 1999 
CHEVROLET   MALIBU      3.1L V6              1997 1999 
CHEVROLET   MONTE CARLO 3.8L V6              1998 1998 
OLDSMOBILE  ALERO       3.4L V6              1999 2003 
OLDSMOBILE  BRAVADA     4.3L V6              1998 2000 
OLDSMOBILE  CUTLASS     3.1L V6              1997 1999 
PONTIAC     GRAND AM    2.4L L4              1996 1998 
PONTIAC     GRAND AM    3.4L V6              1999 2003 
PONTIAC     GRAND PRIX  3.8L V6              1998 1998 
PONTIAC     GRAND PRIX  3.8L V6 Supercharged 1998 1998 
PONTIAC     SUNFIRE     2.2L L4 OHV          1999 2002 
PONTIAC     SUNFIRE     2.4L L4              1996 1998 
PONTIAC     SUNFIRE     2.4L L4              1999 2002
```

Comment: How does listing the different vehicles this alternator fits on help the OP?  Am I missing something implied there?

Comment: Well it was Advance Auto, The guy said it had to be a Bosch, said no other brand would work. Seemed odd to me that I only had one option and had to buy this brand which happen to cost 50 bucks more than sum other brands

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski the implicit part is that the OP should in theory be able to ask for an alternator for any of the above-mentioned models and get the same alternator. I say in theory because the mounting brackets may differ, but (with the possible exception of the regulator) the internals should be the same. More on that in the link provided.

Comment: Listing the different vehicles that a part fits on is irrelevant.  The auto parts store doesn't keep identical parts on a different shelf for each vehicle.  They stock them and look them up by part number.  Your first sentence answers the question though.

Answer (score 1):

In @Chris's comment, he says it was the guy at the auto parts store who told him that the only alternator he could get was a Bosch brand.

This leads me to believe that what has gotten lost in this question is that the auto parts store was simply out of stock of other brands.

Auto parts stores are not a warehouse and only keep a few of each item on hand.  They can usually ship in your needed part within two days for free.